# Android Studio upgrade to 2.2 leads to error: Gradle sync failed: No such property: packageApplicationTask

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just updated my Android Studio from 2.1 to 2.2, and my project went from working fine to having an error:

> Gradle sync failed: No such property: packageApplicationTask for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApkVariantOutputData

#### build.gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/repositories/zt-public-releases'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        // This does not break the build when Android Studio is missing the JRebel for Android plugin.
        classpath 'com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.android:jr-android-gradle:1.0.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

#### gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
    #Mon Aug 22 11:09:46 PDT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

If I can add any other files that might help solve this issue, I'll happily do so, but I don't know what might be useful at this point.  Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of your JRebel import. This fixed it for me. The fact that they have to put a message in there saying it doesn't break it is sketchy in its own right.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed following line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.android'
```

And It worked like a charm